# Is this backslash a typo here in showing a function?

Tags: definition

> "Then there exists a homogeneous function $\rho\in C^\infty(R^n \backslash\{0\},R^n)$ with negative degree of homogeneity which specifies the following properties:"  - Pablo Monzon (2006), Almost global stability of dynamical systems, page 27., [Link to the e-book](http://www.fing.edu.uy/iie/publicaciones/2006/Mon06a/Mon06a.pdf)

Does backslash have a meaning in this context in math. According to [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Backslash.html) it can sometimes have meaning. But, does it have one here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it has a common meaning. In general for two sets $A$ and $B$,
$$
A\backslash B \equiv A\text{ without } B
$$
so in your case, $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$ means $\mathbb{R}^n$ without the origin $0$ or
$$
\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}\equiv\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:||x||>0\}
$$
As Daan Michiels points out, the notation of *set difference* does sometimes vary, for example 
$$
\mathbb{R}^n - \{0\}\equiv\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}
$$
is also used to express this. You might also have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement
It is sometimes written as $\mathbb{R}^n - \{0\}$.

Comment: @DaanMichiels that's true (+1 for your answer), but I know it mostly in the form of $A\backslash B$

Comment: Yes, I also use the backslash, but I often see the minus-sign. The TeX command for the backslash is actually explicitly called \setminus, so it seems like a good choice.

Comment: @DaanMichiels updated the answer! I didn't know that there was an explicit $\TeX$ command for this, thanks for this info!

Comment: Yes, `\setminus` was a good tip actually!